# add checkbox with center alignment in a column of qtableview in pytq5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I would like to add a column of checkbox to my qtableview. I need the checkboxes to be in the center of column (i.e. aligned center). I have this example which works fine, BUT the checkboxes are aligned left.

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5 import QtCore, Qt
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCheckBox, QHBoxLayout, QItemDelegate, QTableView, QWidget, QApplication, QMainWindow


class MyCheckboxDelegate(QItemDelegate):
  
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        check = QCheckBox(parent)
        check.clicked.connect(self.currentIndexChanged)
        return check

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        model.setData(index, editor.checkState())

    @pyqtSlot()
    def stateChanged(self):
        self.commitData.emit(self.sender())

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        print(data)
        self._data = data

    def rowCount(self, index=None):
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, parnet=None):
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole or role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
                if self._data.columns[index.column()]=='Delete':
                    return ''
                value = self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]
                return str(value)
class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        table_model = TableModel(pd.DataFrame([['', ''], ['','']]))
        self.table_view = QTableView()
        self.table_view.setModel(table_model)
        self.table_view.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, MyCheckboxDelegate(self))

        for row in range(0, table_model.rowCount()):
            self.table_view.openPersistentEditor(table_model.index(row, 0))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table_view)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MyWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

To force them to come at center, I create a widget, add a layout and add the check box to the layout. In other words, I change the `createEditor` function of `MyCheckboxDelegate` as follows:

```
def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
    w = QWidget(parent)
    layout = QHBoxLayout(w)
    check = QCheckBox(parent)
    check.clicked.connect(self.currentIndexChanged)
    check.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
    layout.addWidget(check)
    layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    return w
```

The problem is that now, the `setModelData` will not be called anymore. I need to access `model' after a checkbox is clicked.

Has anybody an idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Item delegates are able to set model data as long as the editor has a [user property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html), and a basic QWidget doesn't.

The solution is to create a QWidget subclass that implements that property, and connect the checkbox to a signal that will actually do the same as before:

```
class CenterCheckBox(QWidget):
    toggled = pyqtSignal(bool)
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.check = QCheckBox()
        layout.addWidget(self.check, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.check.setFocusProxy(self)
        self.check.toggled.connect(self.toggled)
        # set a 0 spacing to avoid an empty margin due to the missing text
        self.check.setStyleSheet('color: red; spacing: 0px;')

    @pyqtProperty(bool, user=True) # note the user property parameter
    def checkState(self):
        return self.check.isChecked()

    @checkState.setter
    def checkState(self, state):
        self.check.setChecked(state)


class MyCheckboxDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        check = CenterCheckBox(parent)
        check.toggled.connect(lambda: self.commitData.emit(check))
        return check

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        model.setData(index, editor.checkState)
```

Note that:

- it's usually better to use QStyledItemDelegate, which is more consistent with the overall application appearance;
- you should always check the column (or row) before returning the editor and do the same (or at least check the editor) in `setModelData()`, or, alternatively, use `setItemDelegateForColumn()`;